# jQuery Hiding a <TD> if he has a " " (Space, not &nbsp;)

Tags: jquery, css

The HTML code

```
<table class="wrap_class_adv">
    <tr>
        <td>321</td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td> </td>    <--- HERE
    </tr>
</table>
```

The jQuery Code

```
$('.wrap_class_adv tr').each(function () {
    if ($(this).find('td').text() === " ") {
        $(this).class('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yeqgtb06/

How do I hide the TD that contains a space using visibility: hidden?

Comment: Based on the downvoted answers, please tell us if you meant a (in numbers one) space or multiple spaces (general meaning of a)?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to link jQuery, than you try to set `class`, but setting `css`.

See my fiddle:

```
<table class="wrap_class_adv">
    <tr>
        <td>321</td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
$('.wrap_class_adv td').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() === " ") {
        $(this).addClass('hidden');
    }
});
</script>

<style>
    td {border:1px solid #000;}
    .hidden {visibility: hidden;}
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yeqgtb06/26/

PS. don't forget to link jQuery.

Comment: Visibility is better, with display: none, you also have to worry about preserving table layout, colspans, etc.

Comment: @dfsq: in this case maybe removing `border` do the same, or not?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. For each `tr` you are trying to find `td` which contain a space.

What you can do is, do a `filter` on the `td` returning only those `td` which contain a space, and then changing the `css` as required.

**Note**: It won't matter if there is one space or multiple spaces or even no space and just empty. But, if there is `&nbsp;` then it will not be affected as mentioned by you in the question title.

```js
$('.wrap_class_adv tr').each(function () { // for each tr
    $(this).find("td").filter(function() { // filter td 
        return (this.innerText == "");     // whose innerText is empty
    }).css('visibility', 'hidden');        // apply visibility to css
});
```

```css
td { border: 1px solid #000; padding: 4px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="wrap_class_adv">
    <tr>
        <td>321</td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td> </td>    <!-- One space -->
        <td>   </td>  <!-- Three spaces -->
        <td>&nbsp;</td>  <!-- &nbsp; is visible -->
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to hide any element containing a space, even if it contains other text, use the contains selector, like this

```
$("td:contains(' ')")
```

If you want to hide the elements that contain a space character only, you probably have to select them all then iterate the result and check their contents:

```
$('td').each(function() {
    if ($(this).html() == ' ')
        $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a class to td:

http://jsfiddle.net/elennaro/yeqgtb06/28/ code here does exactely what you want hides td and not tr

CSS:

```
td {
border:1px solid #000;
}
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.wrap_class_adv tr').each(function () {
    $(this).find('td').each(function () {
        if($(this).text().trim() === "")
        $(this).addClass('hidden');
    });
});
});
```